# Variable scope in Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning rails and I have a test app in which I have listings and locations. There's a many-to-many relationship between them. My index page lists the listings, and provides (in construction) filtering functionality that includes checking locations. This is (partially) done with this, in the `index.html.erb` file:

```
<ul class = "list-inline">
    <% @locations.each do |location| %>
      <li> <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" value="<%= location.id %>" id="inlineCheckbox1"> <%= location.name %> </label></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

It does the job of displaying all locations with a checkbox to the left of each name.

Now, when adding or editing a listing, I need to let the user select which locations, apply to the listing, so I follow the same idea, and in the `_form.html.erb` file I have the following code as part of the form:

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
    <option value="<%=location.id%>"><%=location.name%></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

But this time, I get the following error, whenever going to the new or edit pages:

`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

with the

`<% @locations.each do |location| %>`

line being highlighted.

What am I missing?

(I have omitted code that I thought is irrelevant for the issue in order to now overwhelm you, but I may be wrong).

**SOLUTION**
Thanks for jumping in with your answers. Sorry I couldn't reply before, as I was at work and without access to my code.
I feel very sheepish... I was missing what is now obvious. The code for my New and Edit actions in the controller needed to have:

`@locations = Location.all`

Most of you said that in one way or another. I had to choose one answer and I did the one that appeared to me as the most straightforward, being also in comments on the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: you can't call `@locations` in `_form.html.erb`.  `@locations` should be called in `index.html.erb`. That's why it works with the first code but not with `_form`. post your locations controller please.

Comment: @WaliAli That's not true. The @ variable is available in the partial as well as long as it is within the views rendered by corresponding action. I think in this case, he forgot to fetch the record from the database first

Comment: @charinten you would be correct if the `_form.html.erb` is rendered by `index.html.erb` and `@locations` is set in the corresponding action (`def index end`). but I'm thinking that `_form.html.erb` is being rendered by `app/views/locations/new.html.erb` though it's not clear from question who is rendering the `_form.html.erb`

Comment: @WaliAli Yeah, my point here is that we can still use the `@variable` in partial view. Of course the problem here is that he might not have that in his corresponding action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check your action to make sure you have the @ variable in your action. I imagine it should be like this

```
@listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
@locations = @listing.locations
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `@locations` is set in your `index` action, but it does't live forever. Just long enough for the index page to render. You can either set it again in your edit action, or just change your code to this:

```
<% Location.all.each do |location| %>
```

Comment: Fairly poor practice to be set in the view.  That should be set to an instance variable in the controller.

Comment: That depends entirely on how it is being used. If this is a partial called from multiple locations, and you really want all locations every time, then it makes tons of sense to do it in the view. I agree 100% you don't want lots of business logic in the view, but this could hardly be called heavy logic.

Comment: Really you should be passing local variables to do that though.  Controllers are where you should have logic to instantiate objects from the database.

Comment: I wouldn't use a local if the behavior wasn't variable. That would just spill local concerns all over my app. You're making assumptions about the application, and then solving for those assumptions. The right answer might be a helper rather than a local, depending on the situation. Or, because the "logic" is ridiculously simple in this case, it is fine to just do it in the view.

Comment: You were the one saying, "If this is a partial called from multiple locations".  But regardless, I agree that these are just assumptions.  The logic is simple, but that doesn't mean you should ignore best practices.

Comment: Just because it's a partial doesn't mean everything in it has to be parameterized. Would you really prefer that we call `Location.all` in a dozen places (and have to edit it later in a dozen places)? I genuinely don't get what you're arguing for, except to simply parrot "don't put logic in your views" which doesn't really apply here. The Rails documentation does this all over the docs for `FormBuilder`. It is super common in rails apps when you're building forms off a reference model like this and it would be wrong to blow it all out into all your actions.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be setting your `@locations` in your new action.
You can set it like this:

```
@locations = Location.all
```

In this case, however, I would like to recommend using a [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select):

```
<%= f.collection_select(:location, Location.all, :id, :name, {multiple: true})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Local Vars**

The problem, without seeing your controller or model, will be with your use of a `partial`

Rails `partials` don't use the same `@instance variables` as their parent views - you have to [pass `local` vars](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) to them (probably because they're designed to be used in many parts of an app; consequently passing local vars keeps them consistent):

```
#Parent
<%= render partial: "form", locals: { locations = @locations } %>

#_form.html.erb
<% locations.each do |location| %>
```